# Windows Mobile Device Center - How do we clear the list of previously installed programs?

Tags: windows, windows-ce

I have a device with Windows CE 6.00. From its Control Panel, I have opened Remove Programs and removed all of its programs. There are now no more programs listed in its internal Remove Programs dialog. This is good.

I also have Windows Mobile Device Center (WMDC) 6.1 installed on my PC. When I plug in my Windows CE 6.00 device via USB, it connects to WMDC, from which I can click Programs and Services > More > Add/Remove Programs.

First it retrieves the programs from the mobile device.

[image: Retrieving Programs]

Then it displays a list of programs that I have previously installed from the PC. **How do I clear this list of previously installed programs?**

[image: Displaying Previously Installed Programs]

Answer (score -1):

If you install a program to mobile device from PC side, even you uninstall the program from device, PC is still keep the record of install programs in device in registry:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AppMgr\Apps**

It is listed all the installed programs under above registry key. You can locate and delete registry entry of the program which not require to list in Add/Remove programs of mobile device center